# VS Code Python tests debugging timeout

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

When I am debugging `pytest` tests in vscode, the debugger suddenly stops. I start the debugging by creating a breakpoint, then clicking the `Debug Test` link over the test name. The debugger starts, it gets to the line with the breakpoint, the local variables get printed out in the view. But then, after 10 seconds the debugger stops or sometimes it doesn't stop (so the buttons with `Step Over` etc. don't disappear, but I can only click pause, stop or restart, I cannot step over/into etc.).

The error I get from the debug console:

(this is a big stack trace, so I am pasting the obvious cause, I guess)

```sh
   pytest.fail("Timeout >%ss" % timeout)
  File "/home/dabljues/.local/share/virtualenvs/foo-NUiHRnoi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/outcomes.py", line 128, in fail
    raise Failed(msg=msg, pytrace=pytrace)
Failed: Timeout >10.0s
```

This is the pytest-related part of my settings:

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
}
```

Do you guys have any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have a pytest extension installed to flag anything that takes longer than a set amount of time?

Comment: I have Python extension installed. And then the flask icon appears on the sidebar, where I can explore my tests. It's fine, cuz I can run them, but I cannot debug them cuz of the timeout

Comment: Sorry, bad wording on my part. When I said "pytest extension" I meant "pytest plug-in" as pytest itself is doing the exception raising and so there's not specific to the Python extension that is causing this.